# Unable to Install Python Wheel Package to Azure Synapse Apache Spark Pool

Tags: azure-synapse

I am using the following guide to install Python package

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/spark/apache-spark-manage-python-packages#install-wheel-files

I have uploaded the package as seen in the image

[image]

However, the option to select from workspace packages is greyed out

[image]

Can someone let me know if there is something that I need to enable to be provided with the option to "select from workspace packages"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***How to Select from workspace packages ?***

Go to ***Manage*** -> ***Workspace Packages*** -> Upload ***Wheel package*** then -> Go to ***Apache Spark pool*** -> ***select Packages*** -> ***Select from Workspace Packages***

[image: Ref3]

[image: Ref4]

[image: Ref5]

[image: Ref6]
**Reference:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toCK5WANayc

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlVPpNC0aZY